# mySQL delete query optimisation

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: food and moos.

- foos is indexed on start_date
- moos has foos.id as a foreign key

foos is very large (millions of records). moos is not (100k records).

I need to do something rather simple: delete records from foos with a start_date < X and not referenced in moos. I hope it is not too specific a question, but I just can't get it to work (it hangs for ever) I tried what I thought would be "usual" ways:

```
delete foos FROM foos LEFT JOIN moos ON foos.id = moos.foo_id WHERE moos.foo_id is null AND foos.start_date < "2013-05-30";

delete foos FROM foos WHERE start_date < "2013-05-30" AND id NOT IN (select foo_id from moos where foo_id is not null);
```

I should add:

- I always choose X so that I know the number of moos with start_date < X is not big (<> 200/300k records)
- only a few thousands moos reference a foo
- I am on mySQL 5.5 so I can't explain a "delete" but when I replace by "select 1" the explain suggests mySQL is doing what I thought it would:

  - first use the start_date index to find the right foos
  - then look at moos
    so it should not be such a "long" transaction…

Is there a better way to do this, or am I missing something?

Thanks,

PJ

Comment: moos.foo_id is null? why joining null field

Comment: I am not sure I follow - it's a left join, so it should not be a problem, should it?

Comment: Is there an index on start_date?

Comment: I don't mean to be old fashioned, why not place a limit on the query (LIMIT 0,5000) followed by a single query to see if there is still linked data and get the amount remaining in the table. All of this of course, in a while loop (while remaining total != 0). Just a thought for a temp solution unless you are planning on doing this regularly for millions of rows of data. (I use alot of temporary work arounds til i figure out an answer although I guess you will want an answer)

Comment: @neutrino: yes. Adsy2010 unfortunately I do need to do this often...

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
CREATE TABLE foos_new
SELECT *
FROM
    foos
LEFT JOIN moos on foos.id = moos.foo_id
WHERE
    moos.foo_id IS NOT NULL
    OR
    (
        moos.foo_id IS NULL AND
        foos.start_date >= "2013-05-30"
    );
```

Then DROP the original table and rename the new one to foos. Plus add any indexes of course.

Comment: Thanks George. But I am not sure it will be much better - it means duplicating millions of records...

Comment: If you have the space to experiment it's worth giving it a go, as I understand it this approach allows more sequential writes than random ones which can be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Another thought:

The foreign key could be the problem if doing cascaded deletes as for every delete from foo it would also have to check moo to see if there are now any orphan records. Yes, it shouldn't need to as you're only deleting unmatched ones but the query planner may not be that clever.

Comment: Yes, there must be something with the query planner. I think I will need to try and find a 5.6 install to explain the delete query.

Answer (score 0):

Query #1 won't work, because `foos.id = moos.foo_id` only works if `moos.foo_id` is not NULL. NULL compared to anything including NULL results in `false`. And adding `and moos.foo_id is null` will result in no records matching the condition.

I don't see any reason for Query #2 not to work. How long will `select foo_id from moos where foo_id is not null` run? I would add `distinct` there BTW.

Query #2 could also be rewritten like

```
delete foos FROM foos
WHERE start_date < "2013-05-30" 
  AND exists (select foo_id from moos where foo_id = foos.id);
```

Comment: Thanks Victor. On your 1st comment though: I am pretty sure it works since it is a left join. Cf here for example: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: Er, yes, it will work for outer join. Please let me know subquery running time and did my query work.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding an index to the Moos table on foo_id and it solved the problem.
I am not sure why it was necessary to be honest (considering Moos is not a large table)...

Thanks all for taking the time to help.

PJ